# How can I read my hard drive smart status in powershell?

Tags: powershell, hard-drive

I am using Powershell version 5.1 and I am wondering how can I read my hard drive smart status there. Is there any code we can write in Powershell to get the hard drive smart status ?

As in command prompt, as mentioned in the [following tutorial](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hard-disk-drive-health) to get the hard drive smart status, we can type **wmic and hit Enter. Then type diskdrive get status and hit Enter.** so just checking if we can do something similar in powershell.